# Outputting a JavaScript variable to use in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, variables

I'm trying to create a javascript/html product configurator where I want to have several stages and output variables into the next stage, lets say:

I'm configurating a car, first step I choose the color, color is outputed to the next stage, the wheels, (im building it so every stage of the configurator uses a different page) as im choosing the wheel color, I can see that the rest of the car shows the color I selected before, and so on through 2 more stages so now that im happy with my car, I want to confirm, by confirming, a report should be outputed with all the choices I made during the process, as so:

```
Color:Black
Rims:White
Interior: Black Leather
Special: Vinil "Carbon Fiber" Hood Effect
```

I think it would be easier if this was all done in the same page, but the thing is, im using wordpress with the gantry framework, and it has this amazing lightbox which im using to make it all more beautiful, I input a link:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/configurator.htm" rel="rokbox [width height]>Configurator</a>
```

and when the user clicks, a lightbox pops up with everything in the configurator.htm which holds everything about my configurator, the HTML and includes for the CSS and JavaScript.

so if I have:

```
configurator_color.htm
configurator_wheels.htm
configurator_interior.htm
configurator_special.htm
configurator_results.htm
```

can I output variables from the first into the second, into the third... and so on, so I can output everything in the results page?

also, I read about local and global variables and the problems global variables might cause, for example, im using the configurator and another user is using the configurator at the same time, if the variables are global, if I choose black will his choice turn to black or vice versa? assuming we are doing this on different computers, of course. to prevent this, can local variables be outputed to the following step of the configurator? how?

As Isaid, im very new to javascript, so it might seem an easy thing to do or an impossible thing, if it is impossible just tell me, i'll try and find a workaround, but I think its possible, i've seen similar configurators, I just dont know how they do it.

Comment: I think the better choice will be to store the values in a cookie using json format or to preserve it in the server using a storage... if you do not have a database in the server side I'll suggest looking at cookies... you can use the [cookie plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) to store and fetch data from cookies and use `JSON.parse()` and `JSON.stringify()` to process the json data

Comment: thank you so much, i believe this will help a lot.
as i said, im very new to javascript, so to use this script i'll just have to include the .js for the plugin and proceed as said in the github page?
Do i have to include something else to use the `JSON.parse()` and `JSON.stringify()`?

Comment: You will only need to polyfill browsers like IE7 that don't have JSON.stringify() natively, have a look for json2, json3 libraries.

Comment: Are you looking for something like php array to javascript variables?

Answer (score 0):

You could append the attributes that you want to use on the next page as URL parameters on the link to the next page. Assign variables to each of the URL parameters and then use them on the corresponding pages.

```
$(function(){
 // append the link to the next page with the color URL parameter
 $('.red-color-selection').on('click',function(){
    $('.next-button').attr('href', function() {
        return this.href + '?color=red';
    });
 });
 // Get URL Params and turn them into variables
 $.extend({
  getUrlVars: function(){
    var vars = [], hash;
    var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
    {
      hash = hashes[i].split('=');
      vars.push(hash[0]);
      vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
    return vars;
  },
  getUrlVar: function(name){
    return $.getUrlVars()[name];
  }
 });
 // set the carColor variable to the value of the color URL parmeter
 var carColor = $.getUrlVar('color');

 // do stuff down here to set your car's color what the user had selected on the previous page. 
});
```

Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/releaf/56xCg/2/) to show you what I mean. After you click the 'RED' link, using dev tools the next button to see that it's updated to include the URL parameter.