# Javascript: Snippet of code, cant get it to work (setting and reading cookies)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, variables, cookies

im currently working on a javascript based product configurator, and i cant seem to set a cookie and pass it along to the other stage of the configurator, im using [this cookie plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) as suggested to me [on another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18494014/javascriptoutputting-a-variable-to-use-in-html), im wondering if i misinterpreted the plugin instructions and if im using it the wrong way, but as i said in the other question, im very new to javascript.
If someone could please take a look and help me with what im doing wrong, that would be awesome.

To set the cookie, i have this function:

```
function changeImage_red() {
var img = document.getElementById("carro");
fadeIn("carro");
img.src = "http://popo.com.pt/POPO/configurador/cfg/page_color/color/red.png";
$.cookie('color', 'red');
return false;
```

To read it and use it, i have this one:

```
function changeColor ()
{
var color = $.cookie('color');
var img = document.getElementById("carro");
img.src = "http://popo.com.pt/POPO/configurador/cfg/page_rims/color/" + color + ".png";
return false;
}
window.onload = changeColor;
```

I think by the code, you can see where im heading, but just in case someone misses it, i want the color of the car (selected in the first page of the configurator) to pass on as a cookie to the second page (where i have a sideview of the car instead of the 3/4 view i have on the first page, hence, i need the colour of the car on the second page to be equal to the one selected in the first page).

BTW, one thing that intrigues me in my [other question's answer](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) was the part about JSON, i dont think im using JSON at all, what would i have to do to implement it? would it make this snippet work?

Comment: this looks fine.... what is the problem

Comment: the problem is im not being able to read the code and the image doesnt change as supposed, also, there might be something else that messed my css, when the `changeColor()` function isnt commented out, the images wont overlay as they're supposed, instead they appear one next to the other, see it yourself please if you dont mind: [link](http://popo.com.pt/POPO/configurador/cfg/page_color/configurador_color.html) please ignore the fact that it stretches, i will put it inside a popup box once it goes live, so i have the width set to 100%

Comment: you have a `+` missing in `img.src = "http://popo.com.pt/POPO/configurador/cfg/page_rims/color/" + color ".png";`, it should be `img.src = "http://popo.com.pt/POPO/configurador/cfg/page_rims/color/" + color + ".png";`

Comment: because of the error no other script in that page is getting executed

Comment: im sorry man, but that didnt solve the problem :/ what could be causing this image misplacement?

Comment: have you updated the site with the change

Comment: once that is fixed it seems to be working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a script syntax error in the changeColor method - missing `+` before `".png"`

```
function changeColor() {
    var color = $.cookie('color');
    var img = document.getElementById("carro");
    img.src = "http://popo.com.pt/POPO/configurador/cfg/page_rims/color/" + color + ".png";
    return false;
}
window.onload = changeColor;
```

Comment: i already tried fixing that when you commented on my question, it didnt work, but thanks for the help anyway, that would give me problems once i solve the other problem that i didnt discover yet

Comment: @AnteroDuarte can you fix it in the site

Comment: thank you for your help, using JSlint i was able to find a misplaced "space" that was causing the problem, i had: `function changeColor () {...` and this solved it: `function changeColor() {...`
I guess thats what you get when you're a beginner to javascript :p thank you so much, you've helped me a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

Reviewing the GitHub page for this, it looks like there is a [path option](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie#path) which limits where the cookie is used:

> By default the path of the cookie is the path of the page where the
>   cookie was created (standard browser behavior). If you want to make it
>   available for instance across the entire domain use path: '/'.

Try setting the cookie like this (taken from their documentation):

```
$.cookie('color', 'red', { path: '/' });
```

Comment: amazing, thats it, i totally forgot i was making every page on a different path!!! i didnt test it yet, but i'll test and post the result back here

Comment: unfortunately it didnt work, i dont know if the cookie is being set, but it is not being read and it is not being included in the url as it is supposed. please [see it for yourself](http://popo.com.pt/POPO/configurador/cfg/page_color/configurador_color.html) if you dont mind, again, ignore the fact that it is fully stretched, it wont once i go live